# Is the function $(x+y)/((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$ bounded for any interval when $x$ and $y$ converge to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the function $(x+y)/((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$ bounded for any interval when x and y converge to 0? What is the rationale behind finding the value that bounds the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render $x^2+y^2=(1/2)((x+y)^2+(x-y)^2)\ge(1/2)((x+y)^2)$ into the denominator of your fraction.  Can you now find a bound on the fraction itself?

Comment: @ccarvalho Oscar Lanzi gave you a good hint and it looks like you aren't even trying to apply it. We will be happy to help but you have to do your own work.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ and $y$ not both zero, we have
$$
-1\le\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le 1
$$
Therefore
$$
-2\le\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le2
$$
The strongest bounds are
$$
-\sqrt{2}\le\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\sqrt{2}
$$
but it's not necessary to find them in order to show the function is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

**A useful trick:**

Let $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)$, then

\begin{align}
  f(x,y) &= \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
  &= \frac{r\cos \theta+r\sin \theta}{r} \\
  &= \cos \theta+\sin \theta \\
  &= \sqrt{2} \sin ( \theta+45^{\circ} )
\end{align}

where $r\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and therefore

$$-\sqrt{2} \le f(x,y) \le \sqrt{2}$$

**Further point to be noticed**

$f(x,y)$ is bounded as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ but the limit, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x)$, doesn't exist since it's path-dependent (i.e. depending on $\theta$).